# Grails _Events.groovy not working on production server, works on dev though

Tags: tomcat, grails, tomcat7

I want to map external directory as resource to application deployed on tomcat 7.
I have already gone through thread here and tried several approaches:

1. I added _Events.groovy and it works perfectly fine on my dev machine(windows 7), but when I deploy same on production server, it doesn't map external folder to the context root.

   ```
   import org.apache.catalina.*
   import org.apache.catalina.connector.*
   import org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader


   eventConfigureTomcat = {tomcat ->
       println "changing tomcat setting..."
       String imageDir = '/usr/imgs';
       if (System.properties['os.name']?.toLowerCase()?.contains('windows')) {
           imageDir = 'c:/usr/imgs';
       }
       println "product image dir:"+imageDir;
       def context = tomcat?.addWebapp('/imgs' , imageDir)
       def loader = new WebappLoader(tomcat.class.classLoader)
       loader.addRepository(new File(imageDir).toURI().toURL().toString())
       loader.container = context
    context.loader = loader
   }
   ```
2. My context root name is rie, and I tried adding the following context in Server.xml, even this did not work for me.

   ```
   <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
   .
   .
   .   
       <Context path="/rie" docBase="/usr/imgs" reloadable="true" crossContext="true" />
       <Context path="" docBase="/usr/imgs" reloadable="true" crossContext="true" />
   .
   .
   .
   </Host>
   ```
3. Tried alises as well as its available with tomcat 7, that too didn't work.

I am trying this out since from 2 days, referred all the thread and tutorials but its not working.,
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have the correct rights to this folder for tomcat? Try to login to the system like `su - tomcat` (or whichever other username you have started tomcat under which) and access `/usr/imgs`.

Comment: thanks for reply, there were no permissions for this user, so I changed permission to 777 and now able to access /usr/imgs using the tomcat user, but still no luck. Any more suggestion?

Comment: How do you change that permissions? Recursively? Through `chmod -r`? Now you must to sure that tomcat runs really under tomcat user. Actually, you were must to did that at first of all. Run `ps -ef | grep tomcat` or `top` to watch the exact user of tomcat process.

Comment: Great !!! this worked. The issue was I did not change mode recursively. Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: @nIx.. After you added the _Events.grooyv, did you have to add any other files or change anything? I added _Events.groovy, but it seems like is not running at all. If I run run-script scripts/_Events.groovy I still don't see my print statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the correct rights to this folder for tomcat?

Try to login to the system like `su - tomcat` (or whichever other username you have started tomcat under which) and access `/usr/imgs`.

Then change that permissions recursively, through `chmod -R`.